# Errors with compiling when trying to install offchain-metadata-tools

Tags: nix, metadata, macos

Hello I am trying to install the [offchain-metadata-tools](https://github.com/input-output-hk/offchain-metadata-tools) library from IOHK and when using nix-build -A project I am getting this error below saying failed in linker phase when trying to connect to the Network.URI . I have been trying to troubleshoot it for the last day but I have had no luck. I am using an intel macbook pro with 16gb of RAM.

```
jmarzak-us-la:offchain-metadata-tools jmarzak$ GC_DONT_GC=1 nix-build -A project
trace: Using IOHK default nixpkgs
trace: WARNING: 8.10.2 is out of date, consider using 8.10.4.
trace: To make project.plan-nix for offchain-metadata-tools-src a fixed-output derivation but not materialized, set `plan-sha256` to the output of the 'calculateMaterializedSha' script in 'passthru'.
trace: To materialize project.plan-nix for offchain-metadata-tools-src entirely, pass a writable path as the `materialized` argument and run the 'updateMaterialized' script in 'passthru'.
trace: WARNING: 8.10.2 is out of date, consider using 8.10.4.
building '/nix/store/4hmcsf7dj3pb3v3w37wbm4pln42y0xpw-network-uri-lib-network-uri-2.6.4.1.drv'...
unpacking sources
unpacking source archive /nix/store/r4azmxsi3p5bjs81gvm2wvwxflap3x4s-network-uri-2.6.4.1.tar.gz
source root is network-uri-2.6.4.1
setting SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH to timestamp 1000000000 of file network-uri-2.6.4.1/tests/uri001.hs
patching sources
configuring
Configure flags:
--prefix=/nix/store/h2rcbnxmw08s6waqcclri9pnmrn5cg42-network-uri-lib-network-uri-2.6.4.1 lib:network-uri --package-db=clear --package-db=/nix/store/qxwbr7zgaar2ww1j21zlbsdq5chnnzvy-network-uri-lib-network-uri-2.6.4.1-config/lib/ghc-8.10.2/package.conf.d --exact-configuration --dependency=parsec=parsec-3.1.14.0-6iSWBB8iDTOE545kctTcd8 --dependency=th-compat=th-compat-0.1.1-LjxiD0nW4NUFjgNxm1UCB9 --dependency=rts=rts --dependency=ghc-heap=ghc-heap-8.10.2 --dependency=ghc-prim=ghc-prim-0.6.1 --dependency=integer-gmp=integer-gmp-1.0.3.0 --dependency=base=base-4.14.1.0 --dependency=deepseq=deepseq-1.4.4.0 --dependency=array=array-0.5.4.0 --dependency=ghc-boot-th=ghc-boot-th-8.10.2 --dependency=pretty=pretty-1.1.3.6 --dependency=template-haskell=template-haskell-2.16.0.0 --with-ghc=ghc --with-ghc-pkg=ghc-pkg --with-hsc2hs=hsc2hs --with-gcc=cc --with-ld=ld --with-ar=ar --with-strip=strip --disable-executable-stripping --disable-library-stripping --disable-library-profiling --disable-executable-profiling --enable-static --enable-shared --disable-coverage --enable-library-for-ghci 
Configuring library for network-uri-2.6.4.1..
Warning: The flag --disable-executable-profiling is deprecated. Please use
--disable-profiling instead.
building
Preprocessing library for network-uri-2.6.4.1..
Building library for network-uri-2.6.4.1..
[1 of 3] Compiling Network.URI      ( Network/URI.hs, dist/build/Network/URI.o, dist/build/Network/URI.dyn_o )

Network/URI.hs:10:14: warning: [-Wtrustworthy-safe]
    ‘Network.URI’ is marked as Trustworthy but has been inferred as safe!
   |
10 | {-# LANGUAGE Trustworthy #-}
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^
[2 of 3] Compiling Network.URI.Lens ( Network/URI/Lens.hs, dist/build/Network/URI/Lens.o, dist/build/Network/URI/Lens.dyn_o )
[3 of 3] Compiling Network.URI.Static ( Network/URI/Static.hs, dist/build/Network/URI/Static.o, dist/build/Network/URI/Static.dyn_o )
ld: warning: /nix/store/v0n14y5q17p050a81ih6w5d0szsncjmv-libiconv-osx-10.12.6/lib/libiconv.dylib, ignoring unexpected dylib file
ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`cc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
error: builder for '/nix/store/4hmcsf7dj3pb3v3w37wbm4pln42y0xpw-network-uri-lib-network-uri-2.6.4.1.drv' failed with exit code 1;
       last 10 log lines:
       >     ‘Network.URI’ is marked as Trustworthy but has been inferred as safe!
       >    |
       > 10 | {-# LANGUAGE Trustworthy #-}
       >    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^
       > [2 of 3] Compiling Network.URI.Lens ( Network/URI/Lens.hs, dist/build/Network/URI/Lens.o, dist/build/Network/URI/Lens.dyn_o )
       > [3 of 3] Compiling Network.URI.Static ( Network/URI/Static.hs, dist/build/Network/URI/Static.o, dist/build/Network/URI/Static.dyn_o )
       > ld: warning: /nix/store/v0n14y5q17p050a81ih6w5d0szsncjmv-libiconv-osx-10.12.6/lib/libiconv.dylib, ignoring unexpected dylib file
       > ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib for architecture x86_64
       > clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
       > `cc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
       For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/4hmcsf7dj3pb3v3w37wbm4pln42y0xpw-network-uri-lib-network-uri-2.6.4.1.drv'.
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/q72i8ylgcspg7sj6gw54bkxxc7g5a089-cabal-install-exe-cabal-3.4.0.0.drv' failed to build
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/c5fwigx4wvpjkbcm8i6ki34zcaw4w8mq-offchain-metadata-tools-src-plan-to-nix-pkgs.drv' failed to build
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
jmarzak-us-la:offchain-metadata-tools jmarzak$
```

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Comment: You are on BigSur or Monterey?